# ¿Hay alguna manera de que un "setOnClickListener" pueda devolver un Int en Kotlin? ¿O de exportar esa variable a la propia activity?

Tags: kotlin

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que al darle a un botón (realmente es una ImageView), "gire" el dado (realmente son 6 imagenes a las que les he asignado un valor y salen aleatoriamente) y me retorne un valor Int. ¿Hay alguna manera de exportar esa variable a la propia actividad? ¿O de que el setOnClickListener devuelva un Int?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

supongo que el OnClickListener estará dentro de una función, si es así, simplemente haz  que  esta  función devuelva un entero,  define una variable dentro de dicha
función y dentro del onClickListener  ponle el valor que quieras, por último devuelve dicho valor poniendo  return(nombre  de la variable)  si me enseñas el código,  te  puedo  ayudar de una forma un poco mas personalizada.